# Call Java program from Oracle database trigger

Tags: java, oracle, triggers

I have a oracle database table which records user's status. I have thousands of such users. Every time a user's status is updated/modified, I want to synchronize immediately over HTTP to some other server. I'll be using a Servlet here. I thought of using trigger to monitor such update. Upon every such update the trigger should fire an event that calls a Servlet/some Java code. I'm novice in Oracle database things. Could you please guide me to a working example similar to my above task? Many thanks!

Comment: Slighly off topic... but this immediately scares me "I want to synchronize immediately over HTTP to some other server". Putting a HTTP request within a update trigger is going to impose serious performance issues and consistency issues ( eg, what happens if your transaction is rolled back after you have made your http callout? ). Consider instead doing something like putting message on an advanced queue which your remote service can subscribe to, or even just a simple "records needed updating" table.

Answer (score 3):

See [Calling Java methods from Oracle DB.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm)