# How to call a java class from a trigger that is in my database?

Tags: java, heroku

I'm working on a project that connects java with heroku. I have built a java class that does the connection with the heroku database. Now I want to build a trigger in my database but I don't know how to call a java class from this trigger. Please can you help me understand this process better?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Java program from Oracle database trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015641/call-java-program-from-oracle-database-trigger)

Comment: You might want to tell us what the database you're using first? because there is different way to do it depends on the database you're using.

Comment: Please have look on this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm. It helps you to understand more

Comment: I'm using the PostgreSQL which is installed as an addon in Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

DB triggers can only execute code within that DBMS. It cannot call external code.

Comment: OracleDB can do it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm

Comment: That's possible only with the Oracle database, Heroku comes with a Postgres DB.

Comment: Hmm... very nice, you should post this as an answer if heroku has it, or allows installation of this.